# what service am I using if I didn't specify geopy.geocoder user_agent?

Tags: python, geopy, geocoder

I am using geopy.geocoder to get coordinates for a large number of locations. I didn't specify user_agent, I only put my email as a string as "user_agent = 'shuning@xxx.com' ". I successfully got results smoothly this way, but I am wondering what api services I am using.

My main code is here:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='shuning@xxx.com')

result = geolocator.geocode(location, timeout = 100)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The documentation for the class explains and provides a link to the default user agent

Comment: Thanks a lot! but what documentation for the class? I am sorry that I don't know where I should go to look for it...

Comment: Granted, I've never used geopy. So I typed "geopy documentation" into DuckDuckGo, clicked the link in the first result, expanded the "geocoders" section of the table of contents, clicked on the "Nominatim" section. It was a very quick process.

Answer (score 0):

The user agent is not there to request a specific API services, but to tell the Nominatim API who is making the request.

You are sending a request with your the user agent simply so the API can identify the application that is doing the API call.

**Edit:**

With your use of
`from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim`
and
`geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='shuning@xxx.com')`
you are calling the nominatim API.
The website for that can be found [here](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html)

You can collect all this information from the docs for `GeoPy`.
Which you can find [here](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
You can use different APIs in geopy.
All of the information for that can also be found in the API documentation.

Comment: I see! Thank you! However, what server (eg, google, bing, other maps) are those results from...?

Comment: I added some stuff explaing it!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark this as answered if it answered your question!